# Magento 2 : Wrong Count of Shop By on Search Result Page If there is Grouped Product

Tags: magento2, attributes, search, grouped-products

I've created a grouped product. And I created an attribute (`multi select`) that is in parent and children products attribute set.

This attribute has value selected only in children products. One option value is selected for each child product. The visibility of children products is Catalog (not Catalog, Search).

When I search the parent in frontend, if the count near my attribute option should be one (1), it counts two(2). Is it a bug or how should I configure my attribute to have correct count?

Additional information : it seems like it is related to visibility of the children products. If I put all of them to "Not visible individually", I have correct count; but if I put "Catalog" I have wrong count. However I do not choose "Search" or "Catalog, Search" in simple children product, so simple children products should not be included.